# page size Issue in mysqlbackup command

Tags: mysql, innodb, backup, recovery

I am facing issue while taking MySQL remote backup using enterprise utility mysqlbackup, the output and the command used to take backup is is as following

```
170717 09:30:02 MAIN    INFO: A thread created with Id '139688192059200' 
170717 09:30:02 MAIN    INFO: Starting with following command line ...
 mysqlbackup --login-path=<login_path>--port=<port>--host=<some_remote_host> 
        --protocol=tcp --backup-dir=<Back_Dir> --with-timestamp 
        backup-and-apply-log 

170717 09:30:02 MAIN    INFO: 
170717 09:30:05 MAIN    INFO: MySQL server version is '5.7.17-enterprise-commercial-advanced'
170717 09:30:05 MAIN    INFO: MySQL server compile os version is 'linux-glibc2.5'
170717 09:30:13 MAIN    INFO: Got some server configuration information from running server.

170717 09:30:15 MAIN    INFO: Server system variable 'old_alter_table' was set to '0'. Setting it to '1'.
IMPORTANT: Please check that mysqlbackup run completes successfully.
           At the end of a successful 'backup-and-apply-log' run mysqlbackup
           prints "mysqlbackup completed OK!".

170717 09:30:19 MAIN    INFO: MEB logfile created at <Backup_Dir>2017-07-17_09-30-18/meta/MEB_2017-07-17.09-30-19_backup_apply_log.log

170717 09:30:19 MAIN ERROR: innodb_page_size obtained from innodb file header 0 is not matching with innodb_page_size 16384 which is read from backup configurations.
170717 09:30:19 MAIN ERROR: Mismatch found in innodb_page_size.

mysqlbackup failed with errors!
170717 09:30:25 MAIN    INFO: Setting server system variable 'old_alter_table' back to '0'.
```

We are using default page size on both local and remote host.

We are using **MySQL 5.7.17**
and backup utility is of **MySQL Enterprise Backup version 4.1.0 (CentOS 7)Linux-2.6.39-x86_64**

Backup run successfully for local databases but can't take remote backup due to above error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Doesn't MEB come with commercial support from Oracle?

Comment: Were there no spaces before `--` in a couple of places?

Comment: there were as it did not produce any error, rather it was related to page size issue.

Answer (score 0):

Get advice from the vendor. If you're using the commercial product you're paying for expert advice from Oracle themselves.

Answer (score 0):

It comes out that Oracle does not support remote backup from MySQL enterprise backup 4.0 (mysqlbackup)  for MySQL 5.7 as of now and Oracle is already working on adding this feature to MEB.

Thanks all for your advice though.